# PHP preg_match_all match any word boundary

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to capture each guitar chord into the `$output array` however I am not having any luck. They are surrounded by multiple spaces:

```
$text = "F#m     Em   Asus   G";        
$result = preg_match_all('/\w/',$text,$output);
print_r($output);
```

My expected `$output` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => F#m
            [1] => Em
            [2] => Asus
            [3] => G
        )

)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$text = "F#m     Em   Asus   G";        
$result = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
    $text =  "F#m     Em   Asus   G";
    $parsedString = preg_replace ("/ +/", " ", $text);
    $result = explode(' ', $parsedString);

    var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array (size=4)
    0 => string 'F#m' (length=3)
    1 => string 'Em' (length=2)
    2 => string 'Asus' (length=4)
    3 => string 'G' (length=1)
```

Comment: Tested this with your own given test text data and everything worked well. Show me the string that failed ?

Comment: Actually, this does work and I thank you for your help. It looks like Toto's answer above might be a little shorter. Do you agree?